# What does the <> operator do in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I was walking through the [documentation of Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html) to setup a quick working prototype.

In the Mapped Tables section I see a `<>` operator in the example mentioned but can't find any documentation for that anywhere. Need help in understanding this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `<>` operator defines a relation between a `Row` in the `Table` and a `case class`.

```
case class User(id: Option[Int], first: String, last: String)

ROW            |id             | first        | last        |
```

So the data first is taken out of the Tabels as an `n-tuple` (left side of `<>`) and then transformed to the `case class` (right side of `<>`).

To make the transformation of the case class work one needs two kinds of methods:

### `Row` to `n-tuple` to `case class`.

```
scala> User.tupled
res6: ((Option[Int], String, String)) => User = <function1>
```

So this function can create a `User` when given a triple `(Option[Int], String, String)` as an argument.

### `case class` to `n-tuple` to be written in DB.

```
scala> User.unapply _
res7: User => Option[(Option[Int], String, String)] = <function1>
```

This function provides the functionality with the other way round. Given a user it can extract a triple. This pattern is called an `Extractor`. Here you can learn more about this: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112

Comment: So on the right side i see User.tupled, user.unapply . Can you please explain what is happening on the right hand side as well ?

Comment: Here you go. Explantion added.

Comment: OKay now i am getting it. One more last question. We invoke the method <> on a tuple. But it is defined in the ShapedValue class. How does Scala infer that ?  Some implicit conversion ?

Comment: Is the proveShapeOf(v:T) method in the ProvenShape object doing the implicit conversion?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a scala operator, it's a method defined by slick's [ShapedValue](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/Shape.scala#L276) class

As you can see in the documentation you linked, it's used to map a projection to and from a case class providing two methods

```
 def * = (id.?, first, last) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you [clone the Slick source repo](https://github.com/slick/slick) and grep for `def <>`, you'll find that `<>` is a method of [`ShapedValue`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.lifted.ShapedValue) that returns a [`MappedProjection`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.lifted.MappedProjection).

Comment: Yes checking out the code helps a lot. Am still new to Scala so facing frequent doubts on obvious things. :D  Thanks !

Comment: So i see the <> method is invoked on a tuple. How does scala resolve the method on the ShapedValue object ? I think its being done by a implicit conversion but cant figure it out. Let me know if i need to raise another question.

Comment: Grepping for the regex `implicit.*def.*: ShapedValue`, it looks like the implicit that provides `ShapedValue` comes from [`BasicProfile`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3b3bd36c93c6d9c63b0471ff4d8409f913954b2b/slick/src/main/scala/slick/basic/BasicProfile.scala#L53). Though I'm not familiar with Slick at all, and since that documentation you linked to doesn't include any import statements, I'm not sure how that implicit gets into scope. You may want to open another question.