# How is the <> method resolved on a tuple by Slick

Tags: scala, slick

[Linked from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840626/what-does-the-operator-do-in-slick/35840836?noredirect=1#comment59391960_35840836)

I came across Slick's documentation and found it mandates a `def *` method in the definition of a table to get a mapped projection. 
So the line looks like this

```
def * = (name, id.?).<>(User.tupled,User.unapply)
```

[Slick example here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/schemas.html#mapped-tables)

I see the `<>` method is invoked on a `tuple` - in this case a `Tuple2`. The method is defined on the case class `ShapedValue` in Slick's code. How do I find out the implicit method that is doing the lookup?

Here are my imports:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import slick.lifted.ShapedValue
import slick.lifted.ProvenShape
```

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import slick.lifted.ShapedValue
import slick.lifted.ProvenShape

Comment: Ensime tells you which implicits are applied - maybe ask your IDE for similar information.

Comment: i am using eclipse. I havent used ensime . Can that be integrated with eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So i figured that one out for myself.
The object `Shape` implements three traits namely `ConstColumnShapeImplicits` , `AbstractTableShapeImplicits` and `TupleShapeImplicits`  .   These three traits handle the implicit conversions concerning Shapes in Slick .
The `TupleShapeImplicits` houses all implicit conversion methods required to convert a Tuple to a TupleShape.

Now in the line `(name, id.?, salary.?).<>(User.tupled,User.unapply)` what is happening is that the the method `<>` has a implicit parameter of `Shape`
The Shape class thus comes in scope for the implicit conversion. And the `TupleShapeImplicits` comes into scope as well.