# what does <> do in scala

Tags: scala, slick

I didn't understand what does <> do in [this example](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-hello-slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/CaseClassMapping.scala) (last line).

I don't know the name of the operator, so I couldn't google it.
I searched with [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/) but found nothing.

Comment: Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840626/what-does-the-operator-do-in-slick

Comment: And it is called the diamond operator, source : https://www.scalanator.io/course/slick#450

Comment: It's just a method call like any other method call. You simply need to look up the definition of the `<>` method in whatever library you are using. It is not part of Scala, just like a method named `foo` is not part of Scala. It has no meaning of its own.