# Slick import diamond operator <>

Tags: scala, slick

I can't find postgres import for slick `<>` operator. I'm trying to create mapping for `java.time.OffsetDateTime`. The error is:

```
not found: value <>
  <> ((Bonus.apply _).tupled, Bonus.unapply _)
```

My `*` method:

`override def * = (id, name, createdAt) <> ((Bonus.apply _).tupled, Bonus.unapply _)`

My `OffsetDateTime` mapping:

```
  implicit def zoneDateTime: TypedType[OffsetDateTime]  =
    MappedColumnType.base[OffsetDateTime, String](
      zdt => zdt.toString,
      date => OffsetDateTime.parse(date)
    )
```

I believe `import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._` should work, but it's not. Everything worked fine without `OffsetDateTime` and method

`override def * = (id, name, createdAt).mapTo[Bonus]`

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840626/what-does-the-operator-do-in-slick

Comment: I tried to import `import slick.lifted.ShapedValue._` and `import slick.lifted.ShapedValue`. Didn't work

Comment: @karjan can you post a complete example somewhere (e.g., github or similar).

Comment: Code is pretty standard. The only issue were `Optionals` and `<>` method. Somehow everything is working now. I'm looking at changes in git and it's all the same. No new imports, nothing... No idea what was the issue. If it occurs again I'll upload the code

Answer (score 0):

You are missing mapping for `OffsetDateTime`. You have to provide an implicit  `JdbcType[OffsetDateTime]` instance. AFAIR default postgres driver do not provide them for you, which is why many people use something like [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg).

E.g. you would need something like

```
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._

trait MyPostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile with PgDate2Support {

  override val api = MyAPI

  object MyAPI extends API with DateTimeImplicits
}

object MyPostgresProfile extends MyPostgresProfile
```

Of course, you need to replace *all* usages of `PostgresProfile` with `MyPostgresProfile`.

Comment: Mapping was there, just updated post. I'll check out `slick-pg` but it would be better to solve it without extra dependency

Comment: If `<>` failed then either mapping was not there or it wasn't seen. This error is almost always about missing implicits.

Comment: You will almost definitively want to use `slick-pg`, since you then get proper mappings from Java-Time types to native types in Postgres. It also adds additional Postgres specific features to Slick, highly recommended when using Slick with Postgres.

Comment: Java Time, Arrays, enums, JSONs... Build-in driver is a kind of placeholder for start. As soon as you stop limiting yourself to primitives you need more mappings that slick-pg provides.

Comment: Ok, but still the issue stands. The same problem appears when I try to use `Optional`
`value ? is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]]`

Comment: Also true - that would lift it to `Rep[Option[Option[String]]]` which cannot be constructed.